# Integration of Knowrob with task planning algorithms

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Knowrob developers,

I studied about Knowrob papers and there is some doubt regarding task planning process.

As I understood, based on task planning with the Knowrob, sequence of actions are certain (for instance, which actions occur before or after which actions) that can be ordered with the "orderingConstraints" property and also they may be decomposed into other sub-tasks. My question is the structure used to find all sub-tasks to make a pancake whether we can call this similar to HTN !!

Moreover, Can we integrate other task planning algorithms such as STRIPS or Graphplan with the Knowrob? If yes, is there any library which already implements this type of planning inside Prolog language? because it could be interesting to benchmark different task planning.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201445/integration-of-knowrob-with-task-planning-algorithms/) by [Robatics1](https://answers.ros.org/users/20457/robatics1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The structures are indeed to some extent similar (in that they describe actions in a hierarchical manner). There has been some work by colleagues in the RoboEarth project on [integrating the OWL representations in KnowRob with a SHOP HTN planner](http://icaps13.icaps-conference.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/day-1-002-Di-Marco-Presentation.pdf), but I am not sure whether the code is available.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2015-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0